# Php append string to php file

Tags: php

I have a this php file;

```
<?php 
 $arr = array(
array(
    "name" => "1",
)
,array(
    "name" => "2",
)
,array(
    "name" => "3",
)
); 
 ?>
```

I want append new array as string.
New string (coming form post):

```
,array(
        "name" => "new",
    )
```

Final:

```
<?php 
     $arr = array(
    array(
        "name" => "1",
    )
    ,array(
        "name" => "2",
    )
    ,array(
        "name" => "3",
    ),array(
        "name" => "new",
    )
    ); 
     ?>
```

how can i do this with php file write

Comment: Look into using [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Comment: Do you want to update an array in an actual PHP code file, and will you be doing this often? This is what databases are meant for, although if you want to keep it to a file, there are generally better storage formats such as JSON or just native PHP serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do such thing. As **Chris Haas** commented, there are better storage formats, such as JSON or just native PHP serialization.

However, here you got a solution, taking advantage of `var_export` function:

```
<?php

//Your file with PHP code defining $arr
$file = 'arr.php';

//A simple declaration
$arr = array();

//If the file exists yet (if not, we start with an empty array)
if (is_file($file)) {
    //Including the file, will act the assign to $arr
    include $file;
}

//Add the new element
$arr[] = array("name" => "new");

//Write the file with the new content
file_put_contents($file, "<?php\n\$arr[] = " . var_export($arr, true) . ';');

//Just for testing
die(file_get_contents($file));
```

**That is a fully operative example of what you intended**, excluding of course form.